# How to make a circle floating window like the QuickTweet Mac app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, geometry

app link: http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/quick-tweet/id505987287?mt=12

How can i make something like that circle? is that a transparent window, or...?
I would like to create something like that in my application. A circle that can be dragged to anywhere in the desktop (even in front of any application wether its in fullscreen or not), and when a user clicks the button a popover appears.
If there's some code that does that, i would be very grateful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Apple's [RoundTransparentWindow sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html).

You basically make a borderless window, set to be non-opaque, and set to have clear as its background color. Then, whatever the shape of its content – whatever is drawn in its content view – is the shape of the window.